# Approximating any convex shape in $\mathbb{R}^d$ with a polytope having $\mathrm{poly}(d)$ facets

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes

We denote by $V(A)$ the $d$-volume of any convex set $A$. Furthermore, given any two convex sets $A,B\in\mathbb{R}^d$, we denote by $V_{A,B}$ the $d$-volume of the symmetric difference $V\left(A \triangle B\right)$.

---

---

**Question:** How can we prove or disprove that, for all $d$-dimensional convex shape $S$, there exists a convex polytope $P$ satisfying simultaneously the following two properties?

- Given the constant $\gamma\in (0,1)$ independent of $d$, we have $V_{S,P}\le \gamma V(S)$
- The number of its $(d-1)$-dimensional facets $\phi_P$ grows at most polynomially in $d$.

Comment: Did you check it for balls?

Comment: Oh yes, good point @AntonPetrunin . I have to rephrase the text to show what I meant. Thank you.

Comment: Anyway @AntonPetrunin even if $S$ is a $d$-ball centered at the origin $\mathbf{O}$ of $\mathbb{R}^d$ , there must by a hypercube (with $2d$ facets therefore) centered at $\mathbf{O}$ satisfying the two properties.

Comment: $V(S)$ is itself upper bounded by a constant independent of $d$, viz. $1$. So what stops you from taking $P=\varnothing$?

Comment: Thank you @EmilJeřábek . I corrected the problem text.

Comment: All right, thank you. Now I am curious how you prove that a ball can be approximated by a hypercube.

Comment: I don't have a formal prof @EmilJeřábek . Let $B$ be a $d$-ball and let $H$ be a hypercube both centered at the origin of $\mathbb{R}^d$. As the length $\ell$ of the $H$ edge grows, $V_{B,H}$ first decreases and then increases, taking values in the range $[V(B),\infty)$. Hence, there must be a value $\ell^*$ for $\ell$ minimizing  $V_{B,H}$, for which $V_{B,H}$ is strictly smaller than $V(B)$. I believe that for such value $\ell^*$ of $\ell$ we have $V_{B,H}\le \gamma V(B)$ at least for some value of $\gamma\in (0,1)$.

Comment: How can we immediately see that this is not true, i.e., that for $\ell^*$, $V_{B,H}$ is not bounded away from $V(B)$ (in contrast with my conjecture)?

Comment: I didn’t say it wasn’t true, I was just asking. But now that I have thought about it, I do actually think it’s not true. Here’s my intuition: for large $d$, $d$-dimensional balls and $d$-dimensional hypercubes alike have most of their volume concentrated close to their boundaries. But no matter how you choose the ratio of their radii, the boundaries of a ball and a hypercube will have small intersection. (Actually, the ratio of the radii is clear a priori: the volume of a $d$-dimensional unit ball is only close to the volume of a hypercube if the latter has edge length about $\sqrt{\pi e/n}$.)

Comment: Here is a back-of-the-envelope calculation, somewhat similar to @EmilJeřábek's. Consider the unit ball $B$. The ball $(1+O(1/d))B$ has volume larger by an $1+O(1)$ factor. If a point on the surface of the ball is $\omega(1/\sqrt d)$ from any hyperplane tangency, then the radial distance to the enveloping polyhedron at that point is $1+\omega(1/d)$, so that most points on the surface should be within $O(1/\sqrt d)$ of a tangency. That is, the points of tangency should be $O(1/\sqrt d)$-dense. But then there are super-exponentially many points of tangency.

Comment: Thank you @AnthonyQuas !  I am now believing that the conjecture is true only if shape $S$, with bounding box $X$, has a $d$-volume $V(S)$ such that $\frac{V(S)}{V(X)}$ is a constant independent of $d$ (for instance, if $V(S)$ is constant while $S\in [0,1]^d$).

Comment: Thank you @EmilJeřábek . Do you see any connection with https://mathoverflow.net/q/429332/115803 ? In the answer it is proven that a $d$-ball cannot be "approximated" by a convex hull of a set of *any* (not necessarily random) $n$ points on its boundary if $n\in o(\exp(d))$.

Comment: @PenelopeBenenati: If you make your new assumption, aren't you *assuming* what you wanted: that you can get a find a collection of $2d$ hyperplanes (the edges of the bounding box) so that the desired convex set occupies a uniformly positive proportion of the box?

Comment: Thank you @AnthonyQuas . In doing that assumption I was thinking about that the constant $\gamma$ is given and can be any real number in $(0,1)$, as wrote in the first condition to satisfy. If $\gamma$ is close to $0$ the bounding box does not help.

Comment: @PenelopeBenenati: Let me see if I understand a precise version of the question with quantifiers. I think you're conjecturing that for all $\delta>0$, and for all $\gamma\in (\delta,1)$, there exists a polynomial $p_{\delta,\gamma}(t)$ such that if $C$ is a convex set occupying a $\delta$ proportion of a box in $\mathbb R^d$, then there exists a collection of $p_{\delta,\gamma}(d)$ half-spaces whose intersection contains $C$ and such that $C$ occupies a proportion at least $\gamma$ of the intersection of half-spaces?

Comment: Thank you @AnthonyQuas for your effort in formalizing my question/conjecture. The intersection $H$ of half-spaces you mentioned does not have to contain $C$. The symmetric difference between $H$ and $C$ must have a $d$-volume that it at most $\gamma$ times the $d$-volume of $C$, for any constant $\gamma\in (0,1-\delta)$. The number of the half-spaces generating $H$ must be a polynomial $p_{\delta,\gamma}(d)$. I think this problem is quite different from the one above the original post, and so I should write a new question.

Comment: Sounds good. I agree it's good practice to write a new question rather than editing the old one. I would suggest referring to the previous question and indicating that the comments on it have been taken into account in the re-formulated version. Otherwise people who don't remember the details may think you're simply re-posting a previously unanswered question (which is frowned upon)

Comment: Thank you @AnthonyQuas , posted. By the way, yesterday I meant $\gamma\in (0,1/\delta-1)$ in place of $\gamma\in (0,1-\delta)$.