# Approximating any $d$-dimensional convex shape that occupies a constant fraction of its bounding box with a polytope having $\mathrm{poly}(d)$ facets

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes

Given any convex set $A\in\mathbb{R}^d$, we denote by $V(A)$ its $d$-volume. Furthermore, given any two convex sets $A_1,A_2\in\mathbb{R}^d$, we denote by $V_{A_1,A_2}$ the $d$-volume of the symmetric difference $V\left(A_1 \triangle A_2\right)$ (informally, a small value of $V_{A_1,A_2}$ compared to $V(A_1)$ and $V(A_2)$, can viewed as $A_1$ well approximating $A_2$ and $A_2$ well approximating $A_1$).

Let $\mathcal{S}$ be the set of all $d$-dimensional convex shapes $S$ such that there exists a constant $\delta\in (0,1]$ independent of $d$ for which we have $V(S)\ge\delta V(B)$, where $B$ is the bounding box of $S$.

---

**Question:** How can we prove or disprove that for all convex shapes $S\in\mathcal{S}$, there exists a convex polytope $P$ satisfying the following property?

- Given *any constant* $\gamma>0$ independent of $d$ for which we have $V_{S,P}\le \gamma V(S)$, there exists an integer $k(\gamma)$ independent of $d$ such that the number of $(d-1)$-dimensional facets of $P$ is upper bounded by $d^{k(\gamma)}$.

---

---

***Note:*** *This post stems from a discussion with Anthony Quas in the comments of [Approximating any convex shape in $\mathbb{R}^d$ with a polytope having $\mathrm{poly}(d)$ facets](https://mathoverflow.net/q/433967/115803)*.

*Note that for $\gamma\ge\frac{1}{\delta}-1$ the polytope $P$ can be trivially identified as bounding box $B$ of $S$.*

Comment: "Let $S_\delta$ be a convex shape with bounding box $B$, such that there exists a constant $\delta\in(0,1]$ independent of $d$ [...]": I am a bit confused about what is being said here. Do you fix a $\delta$ and then $S_\delta$ can be understood as the class of convex bodies (of any dimension) that can be  "well-approximated" by some encompassing cuboid $B$?

Comment: Thank you for your comment @M.Winter . I just mean that $S_{\delta}$ is defined as *any* $d$-dimensional convex body occupying a *constant fraction* of its bounded box in $\mathbb{R}^d$, i.e., its $d$-volume is a *constant fraction* of the $d$-volume of its bounded box. For instance, $d$-balls cannot be part of the class of bodies formed by $\bigcup_{\delta\in(0,1]}S_{\delta}$. Would it be better to avoid mentioning explicitly $\delta$ in the text?

Comment: So $S_\delta$ is indeed a *class of bodies*, not a single body, and I should read "for all convex shapes $S_\delta$" as "for all convex shapes $S\in S_\delta$"?

Comment: I corrected the problem text based on your comment @M.Winter . Thank you!

Comment: I don't think this is true. Pick any $\delta$, e.g., $\delta=1/2$. Then consider the convex shape that is a cube, but with its corners rounded down like a ball. So it is the intersection of a cube and a ball with the same center such that it fills out exactly half of the cube. Then you will run into the same problem as you did in your linked question with the ball.

Comment: Thank you @domotorp . In my opinion (I may be wrong) bodies similar to truncated $d$-cubes like the ones you are mentioning satisfy at least one of the following two properties: **(i)** there is not such absolute constant $\delta>0$, **(ii)** if you truncate a part so small of the $2^d$ vertices to have, e.g., $\delta=1/2$, then it will be approximated by another hypercube having the same center with a slightly shorter edge. - Anyway I think that the discussion in the comments of https://mathoverflow.net/q/433967/115803 can be useful for this specific class of shapes. Is there the same issue?

Comment: @domotorp I think that the feature that differentiates the possibility to "approximate" a convex body in the sense of the $d$-volume symmetric difference defined above, is precisely the fact that, informally, the $d$-volume of the convex body does not "vanish" as $d$ grows. Maybe the definition of the $d$-volume of a convex body expressed in terms of the radial function by integrating over the unit $d$-sphere in $\mathbb{R}^d$ can be helpful (see, e.g., Campi, Stefano, and Paolo Gronchi. "Volume inequalities for sets associated with convex bodies." In Integral geometry and convexity, 2006).